# Jquery,working fine in Chrome, but not in Firefox and Safari

Tags: php, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, safari

A simple list sort function. The function sorts the list items by recent date (data-date attribute). In chrome it works fine but in firefox and safari it does nothing. But also no errors in firebug :s.

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
      $('#November ul li').sort(function(a,b){
         return new Date($(a).data('date')) &lt; new Date($(b).data('date'));
      }).each(function(){
         $('#November ul').prepend(this);
      })
   });
```

Who can tell me what i'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you escaping all your `'`? Can you show us the code that appears in the browser on the client side?

Comment: Why all the slashes?

Comment: You can use jquery method data instead attr like this:

return new Date($(first).data("date")) < new Date($(second).data("date"));

Comment: Edited the message. The code is the client side output and i'm now using the data method. Still not working in Firefox/Safari en still no js errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution. Before sorting i need to use the method toArray(). But why Chrome works without the adding of the toArray code and Firefox & Safari not, beats me. The final code is like this.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#December ul li').toArray().sort(function(a,b){
     return new Date($(a).data('date')) < new Date($(b).data('date'));
  }).each(function(){
  $('#December ul').prepend(this);
  })
});
```

Thanks for helping!